# mysql update query is not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to update a email field with php but the sql doesn't seems to be working.

```
                $email2 = "'testing@example.com'";
                $id = "'1'";

                $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = $email2 WHERE `id` = $id";
                echo $query;

                if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query))
                {
                    /* execute statement */
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    /* bind result variables */
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt);

                    /* fetch values */
                    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                    {

                    }

                    /* close statement */
                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                    }
                    mysqli_close($connection);
```

I'm new to programming. I hope you guys can help me find the mistake.
I use MAMP on my mac. PHP version: 5.6.7.

Comment: You are missing quotes around `$email2`

Comment: $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '.$email2.' WHERE `id` = $id";

Comment: Thanks that was the problem @Pankaj K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are providing everything in your query it self. then try like this:-

```
$email2 = "testing@example.com"; // remove  '' quote
$id = "1"; // remove '' quote

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = $email2 WHERE `id` = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if($result){
// do your stuff
}                
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Note:- try to read the `mysqli_*` `prepare()`, `bind_result()` carefully. then use it. don't go blindly. thanks. Also start step by step.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:-

```
$update="update users set email='$email2' where id='$id' ";
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why this solves the problem? (Because the OP forgot the single quotes around the values.)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not working because you need to add quotes in your field.

`varchar` field always requires quotes because it is a string:

```
 $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '".$email2."' WHERE `id` = $id";
```

Comment: this query will set the value '$email2' to the email field, this isn't correct, I'd say @tryagain (pun intended)

Comment: $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `email` = '.$email2.' WHERE `id` = $id"; Dot around $email2.